# Get ride of Vmware and move to Docker, how to properly setup the Dockerfile or the cointainer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

I am a PHP developer so most of the time for test any application I am working on what I do is:

- Create a Vmware VM and install a complete OS: most of the time I like to use CentOS
- Setup everything on the VM meaning: Apache and modules, PHP and modules and MySQL or MariaDB

Anytime I start a new VM from scratch there are a few steps I run:

```
# Install EPEL and Remi Repos
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm

# Install Apache, PHP and its dependencies
yum -y install php php-common php-cli php-fpm php-gd php-intl php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-opcache php-pdo php-pear php-pecl-apcu php-imagick php-pecl-xdebug php-pgsql php-xml php-mysqlnd php-pecl-zip php-process php-soap

# Start Apache on 235 run level
chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on

# Setup MariaDB repos
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo

# Write this inside the MariaDB.repo file
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1

# Install MariaDB
yum -y install MariaDB MariaDB-server

# Start service
service mysql start

# Start MariaDB on run level 235
chkconfig --levels 235 mysql on

# Setup MariaDB (this is interactive)
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

# A few more steps
```

This is annoying task and I need to do all the time (when I mess up the VM trying new things and changing here and there. So here is where Docker, I think, comes to save. After read a few I know the basic of Docker and I have pull a CentOS image by running `docker run -it centos` but that's all just a bash shell and a basic CentOS image so is my task to install & setup everything.

Here are my doubts about Docker and how to handle this repetitive and common tasks:

- Should I create a Dockerfile (this is my first Dockerfile so perhaps the order is not the right or I am complete mistaken) with the content below and put all the repetitive tasks inside `run-setup.sh` file?

  ```
  FROM centos:latest
  MAINTAINER MyName <MyEmail>

  RUN yum -y update && yum clean all

  ADD run-setup.sh /run-setup.sh
  RUN chmod -v +x /run-setup.sh

  CMD ["/run-setup.sh"]

  EXPOSE 80
  ```
- Should I run the repetitive tasks by hand as I do before on the VM?
- The command `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation` is complete interactive since I need to answer a few questions and set a password, how to deal with this one or any other interactive?
- Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start answering your questions:

- Yes, you could start with a `Dockerfile`. However, I recommend you using the commands straight into the file so that its easier to maintain in the future. An e.g. could be [Dockerfile of apache from github](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/1f1f7d39d5fe5aebeedea6872786b4e3ce0ebcc9/2.4/Dockerfile).
- Repetitive tasks, no. You could save the images of the containers by [pushing your images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerrepos/) to a public registry like [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or you could host a [private one](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) which can be a docker container itself.
- Inter activeness should be worked around somehow with command line options, [bash read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) or passing a file if possible etc. I do not think there is a straight answer to this.
- Better ideas, the usual pattern is to host the Dockerfile in a github or bitbucket public repository and then configure [automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) against [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/). They all come for free :)

There are also many live working examples you could get from the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/). Start searching for an image, choose the most popular/offical one, then you must have links to the `Dockerfile`.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I am using a Dockerfile as suggested by I started seeing a few ones and creating my own. I will push my image to docker hub so anyone can use it but I need to end it first and test ;). I am stuck at step (3) since I am not a bash scripting expert so I will further research this and let's see what I could do. For sure I will use automated builds as soon as I get this ends.

Comment: If you were think you are done with this, please mark it as answer :)